# Xcode Launch Argument Via Cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, firebase, command-line-arguments

I am trying to add the firebase debug launch argument each time I run my cordova app.

The launch argument is:
`-FIRDebugEnabled`

Googling around, I saw people manually editing the xcodeproj file and adding the argument that way. I did that and it works great when I run my app through Xcode but when I attempt to run `cordova run ios` for example, the launch arguments are not being used. It would also be nice to have a solution that did not require every developer who downloads the source code to go and manually edit the xcodeproj.

Is there any other way to specify launch arguments in Cordova? Or am I doing something wrong?

I know there is a `buildFlag` that can be passed in through the command line or through build.json but I do not think that is the correct place for this specific launch argument?